# Spring boot zuul wrong redirection of request

Tags: java, spring-boot, url, netflix-zuul, api-gateway

I am developing an API Gateway to redirect a request to some microservice.
This is part of the application.properties file:

```
#     _____                                       _____.__
#    /  _  \ ______ ______     ____  ____   _____/ ____\__| ____
#   /  /_\  \\____ \\____ \  _/ ___\/  _ \ /    \   __\|  |/ ___\
#  /    |    \  |_> >  |_> > \  \__(  <_> )   |  \  |  |  / /_/  >
#  \____|__  /   __/|   __/   \___  >____/|___|  /__|  |__\___  /
#          \/|__|   |__|          \/           \/        /_____/

server.port=8088
server.servlet.context-path=/PetApp

#  __________           .__    _________                _____.__
#  \____    /__ __ __ __|  |   \_   ___ \  ____   _____/ ____\__| ____
#    /     /|  |  \  |  \  |   /    \  \/ /  _ \ /    \   __\|  |/ ___\
#   /     /_|  |  /  |  /  |__ \     \___(  <_> )   |  \  |  |  / /_/  >
#  /_______ \____/|____/|____/  \______  /\____/|___|  /__|  |__\___  /
#          \/                          \/            \/        /_____/

#Routes for Auth
zuul.routes.tokenGenerator.path=/auth/login
zuul.routes.tokenGenerator.url=http://localhost:8086/PetApp_Auth/auth/generateToken
zuul.routes.tokenGenerator.stripPrefix=false
```

I am trying to redirect the request from the API gateway (http://localhost:8080/PetApp/auth/login) to the service running in (http://localhost:8086/PetApp_Auth/auth/generateToken)
I have sent with postman the request directly to the microservice and it works perfectly.

IMPORTANT: I am not adding any authorization header because this endpoint is not securitized (And it works perfectly) but the rest of the API in my auth microservice is securitized

[image]

but when I try to send the request through the API gateway I get the following:

[image]

As can be seen, the request is being redirected to the right microservice (Auth service) but not to the right URL, because I have an exception for the rest of the endpoints and URL that is being shown.

I have also tried to put the authorization token previously generated and send in the header, but I get the same not authorized

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you use nginx or varnish for this purpose? you could setup balancing, ESI, etc without any coding. What you are doing is replication of functions of existing software while creating extra bootleneck in your system. If your API gateway does some extra things besides forwarding requests then just make it part of your microservice army which sits behind reverse proxy which do balancing and routing stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have already solve it by adding a filter.
Zuul build the full URL like service service defined URL + PATH, so I implemented a filter that deletes the path and now the request are perfectly received in the other microservices.
Anyway I am planing to change end points definitions to have the same endpoints Path than in the ones defined in the microservices, because with variable paths I thinks it is imposible to solve that.
I will also check to use another solutions like nginx or varnish as @Maxim Sagaydachny suggested

```
@Component
public class PathConfigFilter extends ZuulFilter {

    @Autowired
    private ZuulProperties zuulProperties;

    @Override
    public String filterType() {
        return FilterConstants.PRE_TYPE;
    }

    @Override
    public int filterOrder() {
        return FilterConstants.PRE_DECORATION_FILTER_ORDER + 1;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldFilter() {
        return RequestContext.getCurrentContext().getFilterExecutionSummary().toString()
            .contains( "PreDecorationFilter[SUCCESS]" );
    }

    @Override
    public Object run() {

        RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentContext();

        String originalRequestPath = (String) context.get(FilterConstants.REQUEST_URI_KEY);

        //PathVariable change
        URL routeHost = (URL) context.get( "routeHost");
        String modifiedPathVariable = processPathVariableRoutes( routeHost.getPath(), originalRequestPath );
        if(modifiedPathVariable != null){
            try {
                URL newUrl = new URL(routeHost,modifiedPathVariable);
                context.put("routeHost", newUrl);
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                throw new ApiGatewayException( ApiGatewayErrorCodes.PATH_VARIABLE_ERROR );
            }
        }

        //Delete the path because the full path is defined in properties
        context.put(FilterConstants.REQUEST_URI_KEY, "");

        return null;
    }

    private String processPathVariableRoutes(String routeHost, String requestPath){

        if(!routeHost.contains( "*" )){
            return null;
        }

        ArrayList<String> splitedRoute = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(routeHost.split( "/" )));
        splitedRoute.remove( 0 );
        String context = "/" + splitedRoute.get( 0 );
        String realPath = context + requestPath;

        return realPath;
    }
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to disable Spring security in zuul or auth microservice. Just remove spring security dependencies, make sure token passed from zuul to auth...

Comment: Thats not the problem. I have already solve that but thank you!